# How does linq Last() determine the last item?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I don't understand how Current can be null and the LINQ function Last() can return an object. I thought Last uses GetEnumerator and keeps going until current == null and returns the object. However as you can see the first GetEnumerator().Current is null and last somehow returns an object.

How does linq Last() work?

```
items.GetEnumerator().Current
items.Last()
```

Comment: You are confusing sequences with their enumerators. Imagine a book with numbered pages. That's a sequence. Imagine a bookmark, marking a particular page. That's an enumerator. You can have a hundred bookmarks in a book if you want, all marking different places. Calling GetEnumerator.Current is asking for the page that a bookmark is on when you haven't even put it into the book yet; don't do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on `System.Core.dll`:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource current;
                do
                {
                    current = enumerator.Current;
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`Last()` will call `GetEnumerator()`, then keep calling `MoveNext()` / `Current` until `MoveNext()` returns false, at which point it returns the last value of `Current` retrieved. Nullity is not used as a terminator in sequences, generally.

So the implementation might be something like this:

```
public static T Last<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence");
        }
        T value = iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            value = iterator.Current;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

(This could be implemented with a `foreach` loop, but the above shows the interaction more explicitly. This also ignores the possibility of accessing the last element directly.)

Comment: Also, doesn't `collection.GetEnumerator().Current` return "the object before the first element of the collection"? Isn't part of the contract that you need to call MoveNext at least once before Current has a defined value?

Comment: @Lasse: Yes, although IIRC the iterator blocks generated by C# ignore this :(

Comment: `MoveNext()` *is* called before `Current`, in the `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

The very first value of an enumerator, before any MoveNext(), is, in the case of an array, the item at index -1.
You have to do MoveNext once to enter the actual collection.
This is done so that the constructor of the enumerator doesn't do much work, and so that these constructs are valid:

> ```
> while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
>       // Do Stuff
>  }
>
> if(enumerator.MoveNext()) {
>       // Do Stuff
>  } // This is identical to Linq's .Any(), essentially.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that calling `GetEnumerator` doesn't typically/necessarily return the same `Enumerator` each time.  Also, since `thing.GetEnumerator()` returns a new `Enumerator` which will start uninitialized (you haven't called `MoveNext()` yet), `thing.GetEnumerator().Current` *will* always be null by definition.

(I think...)

Comment: The result is undefined, typically null though, but undefined nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [IEnumerator Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) into the Remarks section, they will state the following:

> **Initially**, the enumerator is **positioned before the first element** in the collection. **At this position, Current is undefined.** Therefore, you must call MoveNext to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.

So you have to call `MoveNext()` once to get the first item. Otherwise you'll get just nothing.

Comment: This explains what was wrong with my thought process. Thanks!