# Why isn't IReadOnlyList optimized with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, interface, complexity-theory

Using a profiler, I have found that when calling the Linq extension method `.Last()` on an implementation of `IReadOnlyList`, `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()` will be called until the end of the collection instead of using the index with O(1) complexity.
For `IList`, there is no such problem as the extension method uses the available index (cf. reflector code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872800/541420)).

It seems Linq would need to be updated to support `IReadOnlyList` as efficiently as `IList`.

In the mean time, the only way to achieve O(1) complexity is to make sure `Last()` is implemented explicitly in my class so that the Linq extension method is not used.

Comment: Asking why a language/API wasn't designed a certain way is not a question well-suited to SO.  (generally the answer is almost always "it would cost more and wasn't judged worth it with the resources at hand)

Comment: Or you could create your own extension method specifically for `IReadOnlyList`.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have an `IReadOnlyList` at the time you're invoking `Last()`? According to the code you linked to, the implementaiton checks if the instance of `IEnumerable<T`> is an `IList<T>` and uses the optimized O(1) call if it is. You can verify by doing the same thing in your own extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I don't think there is any requirement that implementations of the indexer from IList<T> or IReadOnlyList<T> perform in O(1) time.

Comment: Implementations of the indexer are not guaranteed to be in O(1) time but generally are.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30756